# Typescript compilation error TS2307: Cannot find module with angular2 rc5 and ngModule

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, module, lazy-loading

I am trying to find out the reason for the following error.

```
app/src/app.module.ts(13,33): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'src/components/test/test.module
```

I am using Angular2 RC5 and created a feature module and imported it in `app.module.ts` file. I am using lazy loading of the module with the router.

`app.module.ts` looks like this

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { routing } from './app.routes';

/* App Root */
import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';

/* Feature module */
import { TestModule } from 'src/components/test/test.module';


@NgModule({
    imports:      [ BrowserModule, routing ],
    declarations: [ AppComponent ],
    bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ],
    providers: []
})

export class AppModule { }
```

`test.module.ts` looks like this

```
import { NgModule }           from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule }       from '@angular/common';

import { TestComponent } from './test.component';
import { routing }            from './test.routes';

@NgModule({
    imports:      [ CommonModule, routing ],
    declarations: [ TestComponent ],
    providers:    []
})

export default class TestModule { }
```

`app.routes.ts` looks like

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

export const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/test',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {
        path: 'test',
        loadChildren: 'src/components/test/test.module'
    }

];

export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

`test.routes.ts` looks like

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { TestComponent } from './test.component';


const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '',
      component: TestComponent }
];

export const routing = RouterModule.forChild(routes);
```

Above error appears when I try to compile `test.module.ts` file with `default` keyword. If I remove it, error disappears. but of course, in that case, I won't be able to use lazy loading for feature module.

Does anyone come across this?

Answer (score 0):

I see multiple errors in your code.
You are importing wrong module in your AppModule.
Your export class name of `test.module.ts` is `TestModule`, but you are importing `DashboardModule` in your `AppModule`.

Instead of:

`import { DashboardModule } from 'src/components/test/test.module';`

You should import:

`import { TestModule } from 'src/components/test/test.module';`

And, of course, you need to add `TestModule` to your `AppModule` imports.

Comment: ah, my bad white writing code example above. thanks for pointing. I am importing import { TestModule } from 'src/components/test/test.module';
Other than that, for Lazy loading of TestModule, we don't need to add that in AppModule. isn't it?

Comment: Add it to imports as well: `@NgModule({
    imports:      [ CommonModule, routing, TestModule ]
})`

Comment: I am trying to implement https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html#!#lazy-load

I should add more files in question to make it clear.

Comment: Updated question with routes files I am using with this implementation. I get this error when I add 'default' keyword while exporting TestModule.

Comment: Still, the only mistake I see is that you are missing `TestModule` import in your `@NgModule imports` in `app.module.ts`. Don't see anything else here that could cause the problem.